# Ruta y nombre de Archivo FileDialog

Tags: java

Necesito saber como puedo obtener la ruta y el nombre de un fichero seleccionado utilizando un `FileDialog`. Es decir que al seleccionar un archivo y hacer `click` sobre el botón abrir, me guarde en un `String` la ruta del fichero y en otro `string` el nombre del fichero seleccionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  FileDialog dialogoArchivo;
  dialogoArchivo = new FileDialog(this, "Lista de Archivos desde Frame",FileDialog.LOAD);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener la ruta total del Archivo seleccionado , se accede primero al directorio mediante el método [getDirectory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#getDirectory--) **`y el nombre del archivo con`** [getFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#getFile--) , no olvidar validar que se haya seleccionado un archivo para no obtener una `Exception`  `NullPointerException`

```
FileDialog dialogoArchivo;
dialogoArchivo = new FileDialog(this, "Lista de Archivos desde Frame",FileDialog.LOAD);
dialogoArchivo.setVisible(true);
if(dialogoArchivo.getFile()!=null){ /* Validar que se haya Seleccionado un Archivo*/
   String directorio = dialogoArchivo.getDirectory();
   String nombreArchivo =dialogoArchivo.getFile(); 
   String rutatotal = directorio + nombreArchivo;
}
else
   System.out.println("No Seleccionó Archivo");
```

O Crear un objeto de la clase  [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html)  y enviar por parámetro el valor que retorna [getFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#getFile--) para luego acceder al método  [getAbsolutePath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()) que retorna la ruta total del Archivo.

```
String ruta = new File(dialogoArchivo.getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
```